# What happened to the [preschool] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

A user created the "preschool" tag but now it's a synonym for "daycare".

Why?

Answer (score 1):

In real life, the two terms refer to different institutions.

However, moderators (Beofett and Torben) felt that questions and answers about preschool are equally relevant to daycare, and vice versa.

Therefore, "preschool" is a *tag synonym* in the context of this site:
Users can still tag things with "preschool" but the system will change it to "daycare."
Users can still search for "preschool" and the system will provide answers tagged "daycare."